# Smooth after simplifying the geometry in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, smoothing

I try to simplify the local 3D model using THREE.SimplifyModifier. After simplifying, smoothing (geometry.computeVertexNormals()), but what I got is still not satisfying - There seems to be some "scratch marks" on it.

original:
[image: original:]

what I got
[image: what I got]

And main code:

```js
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
loader.load("star.obj", function (object) {
                object.traverse( function ( child ) {
                    if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {


                        // decimation
                        var simplify = new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry(child.geometry);
                        simplify.computeFaceNormals();
                        simplify.mergeVertices();
                        simplify.computeVertexNormals();


                        var modifier = new THREE.SimplifyModifier();
                        var simplified = modifier.modify(simplify, simplify.vertices.length * 0.86 | 0);

                        simplified.computeFaceNormals();
                        simplified.mergeVertices();
                        simplified.computeVertexNormals(); // smooth line


                        material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();

                        mesh = new THREE.Mesh(simplified, material);
                        mesh.scale.set(3, 3, 3);
                        scene.add(mesh);
```

Some way to solve it?

Comment: @Rabbid76, what you mean is that it' s inevitable after simplifying, and we can't do anything about it, right? (Thanks for your help!)

Comment: Simplify it manually in a modelling app to get better results

Comment: You could possibly (in this case) iterate over your vertices and set any vertices within plane height +/- some percent to plane height. Otherwise I would agree with 2pha that a modeller can do a better job/provide better tools for correction.